# With C++ API, How to handle FATAL Kafka produce errors with librdkafka?

Tags: librdkafka

enable.idempotence=true

librdkafka version is 1.6.0
Our external Kafka readers expect messages without any gaps or duplicates

When producing with librdkafka C++ API below 3 type of errors can be detected,

1. From event callback, void RdKafka::EventCb::event_cb(RdKafka::Event& event), with event.fatal() == true.
2. From Delivery callback, void RdKafka::DeliveryReportCb::dr_cb(RdKafka::Message& message), with "message.err() != RdKafka::ERR_NO_ERROR" OR "message.status() != RdKafka::Message::MSG_STATUS_PERSISTED"
3. Return value of RdKafka::Producer::produce, is not "RdKafka::ERR_NO_ERROR" nor RdKafka::ERR__QUEUE_FULL

When any of these errors occur what is the recommended error handling procedure ?
Terminate ?
OR
Is it correct to [All the steps from 1 to 4 are part of the suggested solution]

1. Destroy existing RdKafka::Producer object.
2. Re-create RdKafka::Producer object.
3. Using a consumer, read the last message that was written in the topic partition.
4. Produce starting from next message from above #4 last written msg
   OR
   Any other ?

Answer (score 1):

librdkafka handles the error based on it's severity.

non-permanent errors will be handled internally by retrying the failed messages.

for permanent errors like broker down, message delivery failures (on dr_msg_cb) you need to call rd_kafka_poll() regularly to retry the failed messages.

Source :

https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#message-reliability

https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/wiki/Error-handling

Comment: for Fatal error case(permanent errors), if we need to keep calling rd_kafka_poll() , how can we know error condition is cleared ? i.e. all msgs are written ? is delivery callbacks fired in exact order produced order for a given topic-partition ? e.g. say we produced msgs 99-100- 101-102-103-104-105- to a single topic-partition. and Received delivery report for 99. Then we get a Fatal error(e.g. delivery timeout), and we keep calling rd_kafka_poll() as you suggested, then is it guaranteed that we receive Delivery reports for 100 -> 105 after the error condition is cleared. ?

Comment: Since you set enable.idempotence=true it will ensure the order of delivery report call back , 
for detailed read refer this https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#message-timeout-considerations

Comment: But according to the link(https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#message-timeout-considerations) you mentioned, a time out can result in Kafka topic having gaps right ?

Comment: I am referring to "in this case the in-flight messages may be written to the topic log by the broker, even though a delivery report with error ERR__MSG_TIMED_OUT will be raised"